# How is underscore.js injecting this code?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, underscore.js

I'm trying to customize a WP plugin called WP Store Locator, which uses underscore.js (which I know nothing about).

One template file contains *only* some things added to an `$output` variable, and then than variable is returned. So something like:

```
<?php
$output = "Blah";
$output .= "More blah";
$output .= "<ul></ul>";
return $output;
?>
```

The contents of that `<ul></ul>` tag are completely replaced by another function elsewhere. I can confirm that by adding some text between the `<ul>` tags above and it gets replaced on page load.

The function that is injecting code into the `<ul>` is roughly:

```
function custom_listing_template() {

    global $wpsl, $wpsl_settings;

    $listing_template = '<li data-store-id="<%= id %>" id="<%= id %>" class="vendor <%= terms %>">' . "\r\n";
    $listing_template .= "blah blah";
    $listing_template .= "blah blah blah";
    $listing_template .= '</li>';

    return $listing_template;
}
```

**IMPORTANT EDIT**: If you view the source of the final output page, the  is still empty. The above PHP code appears to actually add this stuff as JS in a  tag at the bottom of the page.

**Here's my question:**

I'm trying to check a value (stored in meta, which I can access) of the current `<li>` against values of previous `<li>`'s that are being looped through. But since the first chunk of code (with the empty `<ul>`) is *before* the looping begins, and the second chunk of code (with the individual `<li>`) is already within a single iteration of the loop, how can I store variables from one iteration that can be accessed in subsequent ones?

I want to do something very basic before the `<li>`, like:

```
if (!usedCategories.includes(currentCategory)) { 
    <h4>Current Category</h4>
}
usedCategories.push(currentCategory);
```

But the `usedCategories` array will always be empty since the push from the end of one doesn't carry over to the next.

Thanks for any insight or guidance you may be able to provide.

Comment: you need to find the source of the replacement, js can change the text inside <ul> after the page loads, php has no power over js, since js is running after php.

Comment: Thanks @LeoTahk - the PHP function appears to add Javascript to the bottom of the page actually (within underscore's <% %> tags). When I view the source of the page, the <ul> is still empty and there is some stuff added in a <script> at the bottom of the page. I'll update my question to include that info.

Comment: if you find the souce code of the injection, you can edit or delete it, im missing the quastion now :<